# Self signed certificate on each client pc

Tags: .net, websocket, signalr, ssl-certificate

Each of our clients have a fingerprint scanner on their pc's installed and we made a fingerprint service that is installed there as well.

The fingerprint service is basically a websocket server running on unsecured connection at the moment using signalR and when the user wants to identify on our web app on a verification page, our web app creates a connection to their running signalR server and the communication is working without problems.

The problem is that our web app is using https and the web socket transport is unsecured so we will need to install a self signed certificate on each client's pc on a designated port and we will need to do it autonomously with some script or code. Also the clients may not have IIS installed so i am not sure if this task is possible.